# Anchor TextView to ImageView

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, imageview, alignment

Is there any way to anchor the position of a textView to an imageView? I have an imageView that slides with an animation and want to have the textView slide with the imageView and stay in the same position relative to the imageView. The reason this is a problem is because across different devices with different screen sizes, my textView and imageView don't align the same.

Comment: Please add an image to show the problem. Also I think that setting the same horizontal contrainsts should solve your problem

Comment: post your layout file

Comment: ya picture please